# How can I take down the scraped Stack Overflow post from a third-party website?

Tags: discussion

I had deleted a post on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately it has been scraped on two third-party websites.

How can I take down the posts from those third-party websites?

Comment: There is no way in general to remove material from third-party web sites, especially if they are in other countries. If you are both in the same jurisdiction, perhaps something like a DMCA takedown request could work. (Given ignorance about international law, a DMCA takedown request could work through intimidation even if neither of you are in a country where the concept has any standing.) We regular users of Stack Overflow obviously have no control over what somebody else on a different network publishes or chooses not to.

Comment: @tripleee a DMCA takedown would likely be meritless as long as the site is complying with the CC BY-SA license (and thus there's no copyright infringement), and could potentially result in civil liability for the filer.

Comment: That's assuming they are complying, but of course, we don't know.

Comment: You can try contacting the site and politely *ask* them to delete the information but you definitely can't *take down* those unless, as mentioned, they violate attribution requirements as per CC-BY-SA license... If posts contained some PII that should've never been published in the first place, then they might grant your request if you explain well enough.

Answer (score 5):

You can't forcibly take it down (as long as they're following the attribution requirements and other licensing terms).

By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for anyone to distribute the content under the terms of the license (regardless of your future choices).

If you don't want your name attached to it, you can request that the site remove the attribution information.  Under the license, they must comply with such a request to the extent reasonably practicable.

Of course, you could always ask them to take it down of their own free will.  Maybe they'd agree.